# Computing the measure induced by a Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: real-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem, stieltjes-integral

Summary:

(1). Is the **Statement** below true?

(2). If so, then how to complete my proof sketched below?

(3). Is there any way to compute the integral term in the **Statement** more explicity?

I'm trying to prove a statement(the **Statement** below). I don't even know whether its true or false, though. My settings are as follows:

> Let a function $\alpha:[0,\,1]\to\mathbb R$ be a monotonically increasing function. Define a linear functional $\Lambda: C([0,\,1])\to \mathbb C$ by the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $$ \Lambda f = \int_0^1 f \, d\alpha. \,\,\,\, (f\in C([0,\,1]))$$ Then by the Riesz Representation Theorem, we have a regular Borel measure $\mu$ such that $$ \Lambda f = \int_0^1 f\,d\mu$$ for all $f\in C([0,\,1])$.

What I want to prove is the following.

> **Statement**. Let $[a,\,b]$ be a subset of $[0,\,1]$. Then we have $$\mu([a,\,b]) = \int_D\alpha ' dm +\sum_{x \in S} (\alpha(x^+)-\alpha(x^-)),$$
> where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, $D\subset [a,\,b]$ is the set on which $\alpha$ is differentiable, and $S$ is the set of all discontinuities of $\alpha$. The symbols $\alpha(x^+)$ and $\alpha(x^-)$ means the right-hand and left-hand limits of $\alpha$ at $x$, respectively.

Agagin I say, I'm not sure if this is true. But I just hope so.

Here's what I did for this problem: I partitioned the interval $[0,\,1]$ into two parts, $S$ and its complement $S^c$. Then $S$ is countable since $\alpha$ increases monotonically. Then If $s \in S$, then we have $$ \mu(\{s\}) = \alpha(s^+)-\alpha(s^-),$$
getting the sum in the statement which converges because $\alpha$ is of bounded variation.

Next, we know $\alpha$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $S^c$, so there is a subset $D$ of $[a,\,b]$ on which $\alpha$ is differentiable and $m(S^c - D) =0$. But I dont' know how to prove this.

And lastly, is there any way to compute the integral term in the **Statement** more explicity?

Comment: Your statement is closely related to Lebsgue Decomposition Theorem. It ignores the existence of continuous singular functions so the statement is false.